# Output redirection - output is printed when the the process ends

Tags: c#, c++, process, io-redirection, output-redirect

I have written a `C++` console  application, which (using regular `printf` calls) prints messages to the console.

In addition, I wrote a `C#` console application which runs several instances of the `C++` application.

I'm trying (for uses in other apps) to redirect the output of the `C++` application, from within the `C#` application, to the console.

Here is my `C#` application code:

```
    private static  void OutputRedirection(object sendingProcess, DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        try
        {
            if (outLine.Data != null)
                Console.WriteLine(outLine.Data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static void RunAPP()
    {
        var newProcess = new Process();
        newProcess.StartInfo.FileName = m_baseDir + @"\" + m_myApp;
        newProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = m_baseDir;
        newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        newProcess.OutputDataReceived += OutputRedirection;
        newProcess.Start();
        newProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }
```

However, when I do this, I can see the redirected output only when the process is terminated (meaning that the `C++` application finished running.

Is there any way to make the output be redirected at `Real-Time` - meaning that the output will be printed to the console the moment the `C++` app is firing it?

Comment: If you run only your c++ app you get the output in real-time?

Comment: Yes I do. Only the `C#` app waits for the process to end before printing the output.